# How do I set iTerm as the default terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2, iterm

I want to configure iTerm2 to be the default terminal on my Mac (Mountain Lion 10.8.4), so that when I right-click on a folder and choose "New Terminal Tab at Folder", it should open iTerm.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The New Terminal Tab at Folder service is provided by Terminal, so it can't be used with iTerm. You could make your own service for iTerm though:

[image]

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set p to POSIX path of item 1 of input
    tell application "iTerm"
        reopen
        tell current terminal
            tell (launch session "Default Session")
                write text "cd " & quoted form of p
            end tell
        end tell
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

As far as I know, there is no such a thing as a default terminal on OS X. You can change the default application for `.command` files from Finder, and you can use [duti](http://duti.org) to change the default application for `x-man-page` or `ssh` URLs.

Comment: thank you, I didn't knew I can create services like that

Comment: Newest release of iTerm2 broke this syntax, and I'm struggling to make it work again

Answer (score 1):

iTerm version 3 (or maybe earlier) has an option to set a specific **Profile** to handle certain protocols, SSH and Telnet being the most appropriate for me.

[image: Setting a profile to handle a URL protocol in iTerm version 3]